# Is there a limitation about the quantity of repositories in one organization? And limitation about branches in one repo?

Tags: github, repository, branch, github-enterprise, github-organizations

I'm investigating using github enterprise version to control user's data in our app. But I didn't see any document about the quantitative limitation about the repositories and branches. If anyone familiar with this part can give me some idea about the limitation about the maximum repos belonged to one organization and the maximum branches belonged to one repo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the repository limit for github.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768454/what-is-the-repository-limit-for-github-com)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Sry, I asked the quantity limitation, not the file size limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding repositories, [since 2016, the number is supposed to be "unlimited"](https://github.blog/2016-05-11-introducing-unlimited-private-repositories/).

That being said, I am sure that "unlimited" is "within reason" (if you really were to create a *million* repositories, expect GitHub support to contact you right quick)

For the branches, this is more a technical limit for an otherwise "unlimited" resource: see "[Limit on number of git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13095482/6309)".
Having GitHub display or synchronize a *too large* number of branches would again generate an email from their support to enquire why you would need such a large number of branches.

Comment: In addition, having too large a number of branches (or other refs) can lead to slowness when fetching and pushing, which is going to pose practical problems for you far before it's going to pose a problem for GitHub.